# How to take screenshot of view that contains AVPlayer in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, video-player

```js
func getVideoScreenShot(url: URL? = nil, viewToCapture: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    if let url = url {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero
        imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        
        if let player = getCurrentPlayer(view: viewToCapture) {
            if let thumb: CGImage = try? imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: player.currentTime(), actualTime: nil) {
                //print("video img successful")
                let frame = UIImage(cgImage: thumb)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize!, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
                frame.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: canvasSize!.width, height: canvasSize!.height))
                let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                return newImage
            }
        } else {
            
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I need to fit any video in the given 9:16 ratio view. I am trying to get a screenshot of the view that contains AVPlayer View. I am getting a screenshot perfectly for portrait video but, facing an image compression issue in landscape video. It would be nice if anyone could help to find out.

The output when portrait video:

[image: Portrait_video_screenshot]

The output when Landscape video:

[image: Landscape_video_screenshot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.